# An update to Provider inside a test was not wrapped in act(...) with Jest + React Testing Library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm trying to test my React Application with React Testing Library and Jest but I always have the following error.

```
An update to StoreProvider inside a test was not wrapped in act(...)
```

I tried many things like put act() function around my test but can't be able to remove the warning and get the correct result.

Here's a simplified project that demonstate the problem: 
https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-haslett-6rq34?file=/src/PageContent.test.js

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a working solution.

https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/issues/641#event-3244842083

I have to waitFor an element

```
const { findByText } = render(<App />)
expect(await findByText('STATUS = 0')).toBeInTheDocument();
```